# jQuery: How to see if the current element has a class of X

Tags: jquery, selector, this

Basically, I have this issue. I need to ask jQuery to do this for me:

if $(this) has a CLASS of "level-o" THEN....

It's easy enough to grab a title or an HREF. I know how to look above and below, to parents, siblings and children. But how do I get jQuery to be more, uh, introspective? How can I ask it to look at $(this) selector and tell me if it has a certain class?

This element may have many classes, not that I'm sure it matters. I'm sure this is a n00b request, but I can't wrap my head around it.

.hasClass() doesn't seem to be doing it. Here's an example:

```
<span class="design_menu mid_menu_title" style="display: inline;">
        <ul>
            <li class="level-0 page_item page-item-545 current_page_item"><a title="Jazz" href="http://www.domain.com./?page_id=545">Jazz</a></li>

        </ul>
    </span>
```

What I'm asking is:

```
if($(".current_page_item").hasClass('.level-0')){
            alert("OMG ABORT ABBBBBBBBBBORT WEVE BREACHED LEVEL 0 ONLY GOD CAN SAVE US NO------");
                        }
```

That doesn't seem to do it. Clues, tips, tricks?

Comment: Drop the period before level-0

Comment: in which case @Michael Gattuso's answer is correct (albeit he didn't specifically state the problem was the period).

Answer (score 1):

```
if($(this).hasClass('foo')) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: That seems like the right answer to me, too. So why doesn't it work in my above sample?

Comment: [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) takes a **string** (`level-0`) *not* a **selector** (`.level-0`). Demo, of sorts, at: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aevjb/).